# BottomNavigationView Background Color Refresh

Tags: android, mobile, bottomnavigationview

So we have this app that employs a "dynamic" theme that we fetch from an API call that includes hex colors. We color the toolbar, buttons, bottom navigation view etc with these values.

The problem:

I'm programmaticly setting the background color for the BottomNavigationView in a callback from the api in my activity with the following:

`binding.bottomNav.root.background = ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(primary.uppercase()))`

This works but the issue is that it only changes color when onResume is called again as in you hit the home button then go back to the app.

I've tried using `requestLayout()` `invalidate()` to force a redraw to no avail.

Any help with this would be very appreciated. I've scoured stack for a simple solution to this with little insight.

Answer (score 0):

I think you change your bottomnavigation background color so I suggest you make selector resource in drawable and use material bottomnavigation dependency

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean by using the material bottom navigation dependency?